# regular expressions find string letters, and string letters with combination of string numbers python

Tags: python, regex, list

```
x = ['86050023328185523 THE B WITH PEANUT 140G'],['86050023328185523 ABC WITH BanaNA 40G'],['86050023328185523 B B Z WITH JElly 250G']
```

lets say this is our variable which contains **all strings.** from which the output should be everyting except string numbers in a row.

desired output:

```
 ['THE B WITH PEANUT 140G']
 ['ABC WITH BanaNA 40G']
 ['B B Z WITH JElly 250G']
```

code:

```
x = ['86050023328185523 A B  Z  WITH PEANUT 140GB'],['86050023328185523 A B  Z  WITH PEANUT 140GB'],['86050023328185523 A B  Z  WITH PEANUT 140GB']

for e in x:
    for i in e:
        #print(type(i)) <class 'str'>
        f = re.findall(r'\d+',i)
        print(f)
```

result of the code:

```
['86050023328185523', '140']
['86050023328185523', '40']
['86050023328185523', '250']
```

Comment: Maybe you want `re.sub(r'^\d+\s*','',i)` to remove leading digits + whitespace? See https://ideone.com/OSBo6I

Answer (score 2):

I believe a list comprehension with string methods should be enough:

```
[[' '.join(s for s in l[0].split() if not s.isnumeric())] for l in x]

[['THE B WITH PEANUT 140G'],
 ['ABC WITH BanaNA 40G'],
 ['B B Z WITH JElly 250G']]
```

Answer (score 0):

With the list of sub lists of strings in your example, you can do:

```
>>> [[re.sub(r'^\d+[ \t]*','',e) for e in sl] for sl in x]
[['THE B WITH PEANUT 140G'], ['ABC WITH BanaNA 40G'], ['B B Z WITH JElly 250G']]
```

The `[ \t]` is equivalent to POSIX `[:blank:]` for horizontal space characters; you can use `\s` for all whitespace which is defined as `[ \t\r\n\v\f]` in ASCII.